# Accessing html inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am following this tutorial [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/%20chart%20js) and I want to access the html inside the `canvas` tag but I don't see any in my console, and so I can't access it. How can it be ?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the html"?  If you want different data to be displayed in the chart, then change the data a redraw the chart.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas, unlike SVG, is a bitmap write-only object. It contains no HTML. It's "write and forget".

Updates are made via complete redraw. There's nothing to see but the output.